# I can't create the sails project?

Tags: sails.js

sails new asx I used this command.
when I try to create the sail.js project.I got an error like

```
C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\WebstormProjects\sailsapplication>"C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\WebstormProjects\sailsapplication\sails"
'"C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\WebstormProjects\sailsapplication\sails"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

can anyone tell me what is the error? Thankyou...

Comment: Did you install using npm? Like, "npm install sails -g"? (the "g" is for "global"). If you didn't, you should. If you did, the next thing is to make sure sails is added to your PATH, and that is different depending on whether you are on windows, apple, linux, etc.

Comment: can you tell me how to set the path in environment variables?Remaining I did the same.

Comment: for which operating system? linux/windows/apple, etc.

Comment: I am using windows .I set the path:

C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\sails           in environment variables

Comment: remove the `sails` part at the end of your path. and also why are you adding `C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm\sails` in the path when the script is ecpecting `C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\WebstormProjects\sailsapplication\sails`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I think you were right that `\sails` needs to be removed, but I think that the `\AppData` path is the correct one. The error is saying "I can't find a sails executable in [this dir], so it wouldn't help to add [this dir] to the path. After updating your path variables, close and reopen your cmd console and try `sails -v` from any directory (it just spits out the sails version IF it has been added to the path).

Comment: ok, then remove sails out of the path as it is the executable and does not form a path. if it works, I will post an answer.

Comment: I added  this path  C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\WebstormProjects\sailsapplication but I facing the same problem.

Comment: put a backslash \ after sailsapplication on both path entries you have. Also, are the paths separated by semicolons?

Comment: I am still pretty sure the path you need is `C:\Users\Vignesh Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Try adding that, then user `sails -v` from any dir in the console. No error means it works.

Comment: I added this to my PATH but didn't work until I restart computer. Now sails -v works